# Global Search a Child Element in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Want to get all the details of the ***highlighted key*** without knowing other parent details in the below data model. The model is like ***root/Transaction/UserId/userVehicle/userTransactionId***

```
"1kGqXIjZVwglAK8MEepwVjzmyZo1": {
    "ORpoi3747": {
        "-KSQyvu1ZhiJX78B7FKr": {
            "CarPickAddress": {
                "addressLine1": "fjdj",
                "addressLine2": "ff",
                "carNumber": "",
                "city": "ff",
                "landmark": "ff",
                "mobileNumber": "5656",
                "pin": "55536",
                "state": "ff"
            },
            "agentAssigned": "adssdas",
            "requestStatus": "closed",
            "serviceCompleteDate": "25/09/2016",
            "serviceRequestDate": "09/24/2016 17:06:45"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What *do* you know about the child you want to select? If you only know the `-KSQ...FKr` and not `ORpoi3747` (next time include your JSON as text please, pictures of text are a waste of both space and energy), it is going to be tricky. But if you know the push ID, you stored it at some point. You might as well as store the items entire path in that case: `ORpoi3747/-KSQ...FKr`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you want me to create another objecet and store it like `{
 "-KSQyvu1ZhiJX78B7FKr": "1kGqXIjZVwglAK8MEepwVjzmyZo1/ORpoi3747/-KSQyvu1ZhiJX78B7FKr"
}`

Comment: There is no API to query a grand-child by its key. There is however the ability to look-up a grand-child by its path: `ref.child('1kGqXIjZVwglAK8MEepwVjzmyZo1/ORpoi3747/KSQyvu1ZhiJX78B7FKr‌​').on(...)`. You don't need to add a property for that, you just need to make sure your *app/code* knows the path instead of just the sub-key.